# Ruby on Rails, getting attributes from multiple model instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Ruby on Rails project, I have a Country model class and a Proposal model class.  A country has many proposals and a proposal belongs to a specific country.  Each proposal consists of 30 questions.  I want to display each question for every proposal for that specific country.

My initial idea for syntax was:

```
<% @country.proposal.each do |proposal| %>

<% end %>
```

However, this resulted in an error message

```
undefined method `proposal' for #Country:0x007f67b51cf178
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

According to yous associations, just replace `@country.proposal.each` with
`@country.proposals.each`. `has_many` association define method with a name in plural form.

Comment: when trying to display the questions, "<p><% @proposal_q1 %></p>" doesn't display anything

Comment: @BerryAllen it is other question. Anyway, write full code.